# Using Robocopy in vb.net app Win32 error

Tags: vb.net, winapi, robocopy

I am developing an application in vb.net that needs to use Robocopy to copy directories and all contents within the directories to a specified directory. Robocopy must be used because unlike drag and drop, it preserves the date modified and other properties of the files and folders it moves. I am using the following code to initiate this but I am getting an error

> Win32 ExceptionUnhandled, Could not find the specified file.

I have done my research and this seems to be the most efficient way to call Robocopy... any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles         MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim srcFold As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim destFold As String = TextBox2.Text

        'Dim oProcess As New ProcessStartInfo
        'oProcess.FileName = "C:\windows\SysWow64\robocopy.exe"
        'oProcess.Arguments = "C:\upsdnc\11111\" & "C:\ups\11111_dnc" & "/E /Z /dcopy:T /fft /R:10 /ETA /log:C:\copy.log /tee"

       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Windows\SysWow64\Robocopy.exe C:\upsdnc\11111 C:\ups\11111_dnc /E /Z /dcopy:T /fft /R:10 /ETA /log:C:\copy.log /tee")


    End Sub
```

As you can see I also attempted using ProcessStartInfo but I am told Process.Start is much simpler.

Also, to use Robocopy, the format is "Source folder" "Destination Folder" followed by options as you can see in the above code

Comment: Make sure you quote the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a log file that is in a subfolder of `C:\` e.g. `C:\log\copy.log`

Nowadays you generally can't write to the `C:\` root directory.